# Let $q=\gcd(x,y)$. Prove that if $x\nmid zq$ then $x \nmid yz$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $q=\gcd(x,y)$. Prove that if $x\nmid zq$ then $x \nmid yz$.

I understand that I can prove this using contrapositive, that is

Let $q=\gcd(x,y)$. If $x\mid yz$ then $x \mid zq$.

Assume $x|yz$ and $q = \gcd(x , y)$
then $q|x$ and $q|y$.

Then
$xk = yz$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
$qr = x$ for some $r\in \mathbb{Z}$.
$qs = y$ for some $s\in \mathbb{Z}$.

By Bezout's Theorum
$q = xa + yb$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

---

I'm not entirely sure how to proceed.

Comment: Let $x = x'q$ and $y = y'q$. Then $\gcd(x',y') = 1$.  Then $x\not |zq \implies x'q \not |zq \implies x' \not | z \implies x' \not |y'z \implies x'q \not |y'zq \implies x \not |yz$.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the equations involving $r$ and $s$, we have everything we need. Observe that:
\begin{align*}
q &= xa + yb \\
zq &= xaz + (yz)b \\
zq &= xaz + (xk)b \\
zq &= x \cdot \underbrace{(az + kb)}_{\in ~ \mathbb Z}
\end{align*}